# FB Login Button Not Authenticating

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am trying to integrate fb login in [my website](http://yoloyodoyoloyodo.appspot.com/login). 
On click the button if not logged in fb,it ask for fb credential and then does nothing.
It just send a post request to facebook/connect/ping with a forced 302 status

Here is the code

```
<script>
var isLoaded=false;
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '{{app_id}}',
        status     : true,
        xfbml      : true
    });
};
isLoaded=true;

function checkIfLoaded() {
    if(isLoaded) console.log("LOADED!");
    else console.log("NOT YET!");
    return false;
}

(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";js.async=true;
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        onLogin(response);
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        FB.login();
    } else {
        FB.login();
    }
});

function onLogin(response) {
    console.log('login succ');
    var status=response.status;
    var accessToken=response.authResponse.accessToken;
    var expiresIn=response.authResponse.expiresIn;
    var signedRequest=response.authResponse.signedRequest;
    var userID=response.authResponse.userID;

    $("#status").val(status);
    $("#accessToken").val(accessToken);
    $("expiresIn").val(expiresIn);
    $("signedRequest").val(signedRequest);
    $("userID").val(userID);
    $("#form").submit();
}

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="checkIfLoaded();">Check</a>
<h2>User</h2>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false"></div>
```

In my app dashboard I have just added a platform with the site name as above.Nothing else is configured.

Comment: no...you can go yo the link and check it if you can find any

Comment: What is the your purpose ? 
So if user is logged in, what should happen ?

Comment: I want it to call onlogin function.But its not.

Comment: your code isn't wrong.
Just `data-auto-logout-link="true"` 



`<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true"></div>`

Comment: `http://theonetechnologies.com/outsourcing/post/aspnet-login-with-facebook-and-graph-api.aspx`
I hope this will be useful

Comment: your link is not working, also what does asp has to do with the javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `FB.Event` is not subscribed since `FB` was not initialized when you tried to subscribe this event. See console for the error, you'll see:

> FB is not defined

The reason is that the FB object is defined asynchronously under `window.fbAsyncInit`, so whenever you want to do a API call or use the `FB` it must be done after the `FB` is defined.

So the solution to your problem is that, write the `FB.event` after the `FB` is defined (not before it is defined), just like this-

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '{{app_id}}',
        status     : true,
        xfbml      : true
    });

    // write all your "FB" code here, since the FB is defined now
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            onLogin(response);
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            FB.login();
        } else {
            FB.login();
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Why twice `FB.login();` ?
I think it is enough `else {FB.login(); } `

Comment: See there are three cases, you have to handle all three. I think your basics are not clear with the facebook api. Follow the tutorials pls. http://developers.facebook.com

Comment: But already you call same function : `FB.login();` for two last case.

Comment: But don't you see you call the same function for last two case.
Already if response.status != 'connected' , FB.login() will be called.
why twice else

Comment: Lets end this discussion here. Those three cases are just to check for the developer, that how is the flow going on- if user is not auth, not logged in or both. It has been explained well here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/. That's it. Dont unnecessarily extend this discussion and deviate from the original question.